# Custom Jasmine HTML output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jasmine

I am testing a project in rails with Jasmine which is all going great.

The only issue I now have is that I'm not a huge fan of the way the tests are being displayed. Currently I view my test suite at `http://localhost:8000/jasmine` and Jasmine is pulling in my styles along with it's own and rendering the tests as follows:

[image: My Jasmine Output]

I would like to either render the tests like this (as I've seen elsewhere):
[image: Desired Jasmine Output]

Or have some way of customising the HTML output/layout. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you included your CSS in specrunner or are you pulling in some dynamic styles in your fixtures?

Comment: I don't actually have a specrunner file. I use the 'jasmine' gem and it seemed to just work/give me output out of the box. I've seen references to specrunner before but the docs for the gem don't refer to a 'specrunner' file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The output you want is produced if you use the `jasmine.TrivialReporter`. The one the gem displays is the recommended one, i.e. the `jasmine.HtmlReporter`. You can use the trivial one as described here: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/v1.3.1/lib/jasmine-core/example/SpecRunner.html, but that implies running jasmine stand-alone not through the gem.

(version 1._._ only.)